# How to make sure all my source files stay UTF-8 with Unix line endings?

Tags: unix, command-line, character-encoding, sublimetext, line-endings

I'm looking for some command-line tools for Linux that can help me detect and convert files from character sets like *iso-8859-1* and *windows-1252* to *utf-8* and from Windows line endings to Unix line endings.

The reason I need this is that I'm working on projects on Linux servers via SFTP with editors on Windows (like Sublime Text) that just constantly screws these things up. Right now I'm guessing about half my files are *utf-8*, the rest are *iso-8859-1* and *windows-1252* as it seems Sublime Text is just picking character set by which symbols the file contains when I save it. The line endings are ALWAYS Windows line endings even though I've specified in the options that default line endings are *LF*, so about half of my files have *LF* and half are *CRLF*.

So I would need at least a tool that would recursively scan my project folder and alert me of files that deviate from *utf-8* with *LF* line endings so I could manually fix that before I commit my changes to GIT.

Any comments and personal experiences on the topic would also be welcome.

Thanks

---

***Edit:*** I have a temporary solution in place where I use `tree` and `file` to output information about every file in my project, but it's kinda wonky. If I don't include the `-i` option for `file` then a lot of my files gets different output like *ASCII C++ program text* and *HTML document text* and *English text* etc:

```
$ tree -f -i -a -I node_modules --noreport -n | xargs file | grep -v directory
./config.json:              ASCII C++ program text
./debugserver.sh:           ASCII text
./.gitignore:               ASCII text, with no line terminators
./lib/config.js:            ASCII text
./lib/database.js:          ASCII text
./lib/get_input.js:         ASCII text
./lib/models/stream.js:     ASCII English text
./lib/serverconfig.js:      ASCII text
./lib/server.js:            ASCII text
./package.json:             ASCII text
./public/index.html:        HTML document text
./src/config.coffee:        ASCII English text
./src/database.coffee:      ASCII English text
./src/get_input.coffee:     ASCII English text, with CRLF line terminators
./src/jtv.coffee:           ASCII English text
./src/models/stream.coffee: ASCII English text
./src/server.coffee:        ASCII text
./src/serverconfig.coffee:  ASCII text
./testserver.sh:            ASCII text
./vendor/minify.json.js:    ASCII C++ program text, with CRLF line terminators
```

But if I do include `-i` it doesn't show me line terminators:

```
$ tree -f -i -a -I node_modules --noreport -n | xargs file -i | grep -v directory
./config.json:              text/x-c++; charset=us-ascii
./debugserver.sh:           text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./.gitignore:               text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./lib/config.js:            text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./lib/database.js:          text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./lib/get_input.js:         text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./lib/models/stream.js:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./lib/serverconfig.js:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./lib/server.js:            text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./package.json:             text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./public/index.html:        text/html; charset=us-ascii
./src/config.coffee:        text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./src/database.coffee:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./src/get_input.coffee:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./src/jtv.coffee:           text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./src/models/stream.coffee: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./src/server.coffee:        text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./src/serverconfig.coffee:  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./testserver.sh:            text/plain; charset=us-ascii
./vendor/minify.json.js:    text/x-c++; charset=us-ascii
```

Also why does it display *charset=us-ascii* and not *utf-8*? And what's *text/x-c++*? Is there a way I could output only `charset=utf-8` and `line-terminators=LF` for each file?

Comment: As for a workaround, perhaps you could include a comment with a decidedly non-ASCII character code (the copyright symbol comes to mind) and save as UTF-8 - perhaps this would be enough for Sublime Text to stop guessing so much.

Comment: I also cannot for the life of me get Sublime Text to just use freaking Unix line breaks for the love of God!!  "default_line_ending": "unix" should just work!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is the two Sublime Text 2 plugins *"EncodingHelper"* and *"LineEndings"*. I now get both the file encoding and line endings in the status bar:

[image: Sublime Text 2 status bar]

If the encoding is wrong, I can **File->Save with Encoding**. If the line endings are wrong, the latter plugin comes with commands for changing the line endings:

[image: Sublime Text 2 commands]

Answer (score 3):

If a file has no BOM, and no 'interesting characters' within the amount of text that `file` looks at, `file` concludes that it is <del>ASCII</del> ISO-646 -- a strict subset of UTF-8. You might find that putting BOMs on all your files encourages all these Windows tools to behave; the convention of a BOM on a UTF-8 file originated on Windows. Or it might make things worse. As for x/c++, well, that's just `file` tryin' to be helpful, and failing. You javascript has something in it that looks like C++.

Apache Tika has an encoding detector; you could even use the command-line driver that comes with it as an alternative to `file`. It will stick to MIME types and not wander off to C++.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. As for using Apache Tika's encoding detector... It feels like acquiring a cruise ship to cross a puddle. What I'm apparently looking for is a command line tool for analysing files that will give me the output I'm looking for, which is character encoding and line terminators

Comment: Just make sure the puddle doesn't have a reef. Really, using their CLI is just 'using a command'. I don't recall if icu4c includes a command that would be a competitive alternative, or whether using iconv with the right options would give you a clear error for non-UTF-8.

Comment: Beware that `file` sometimes uses rather crude heuristics - your `x-c++` example shows it making a wrong guess. If you know exactly what you are looking for, a few simple `grep` commands can help you categorize your files.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `file`, try a custom program to check just the things you want.  Here is a quick hack, mainly based on [some](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=921975) Google [hits](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=718794), which were incidentally written by @ikegami.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw( decode );

use vars (qw(@ARGV));

@ARGV > 0 or die "Usage: $0 files ...\n";

for my $filename (@ARGV)
{
    my $terminator = 'CRLF';
    my $charset = 'UTF-8';
    local $/;
    undef $/;
    my $file;
    if (open (F, "<", $filename))
    {
        $file = <F>;
        close F;    
        # Don't print bogus data e.g. for directories
        unless (defined $file)
        {
            warn "$0: Skipping $filename: $!\n;
            next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        warn "$0: Could not open $filename: $!\n";
        next;
    }

    my $have_crlf = ($file =~ /\r\n/);
    my $have_cr = ($file =~ /\r(?!\n)/);
    my $have_lf = ($file =~ /(?!\r\n).\n/);
    my $sum = $have_crlf + $have_cr + $have_lf;
    if ($sum == 0)
    {
        $terminator = "no";
    }
    elsif ($sum > 2)
    {
        $terminator = "mixed";
    }
    elsif ($have_cr)    
    {
        $terminator = "CR";
    }
    elsif ($have_lf)
    {
        $terminator = "LF";
    }

    $charset = 'ASCII' unless ($file =~ /[^\000-\177]/);

    $charset = 'unknown'
        unless eval { decode('UTF-8', $file, Encode::FB_CROAK); 1 };

    print "$filename: charset $charset, $terminator line endings\n";
}
```

Note that this has no concept of legacy 8-bit encodings - it will simply throw `unknown` if it's neither pure 7-bit ASCII nor proper UTF-8.